# What's the proper way to implement Fragments in MvvmCross 3.5.1

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

After upgrading from 3.5 to 3.5.1 I am getting errors inflating Fragments in my Xamarin.Android project.

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx.xxx/md51537e9497dba76724980c8d1dff85301.MyView}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment


Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class md51537e9497dba76724980c8d1dff85301.LoginView that is not a Fragment
```

What is causing this error? Are there breaking changes in 3.5.1?

My Fragment is defined as

```
public class LoginFormView : MvxFragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var ignore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.LoginFormView, null);
    }
}
```

I have included the V4 support via the Xamarin Component store.

I inflate my fragment via:

```
public class LoginView : BaseMvxFragmentActivity
    {
...

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginView);

        _loginForm = (LoginFormView)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.sub_login_form);
        _loginForm.ViewModel = MyViewModel.LoginFormViewModel;
    }
    ...
 }
```

**Update 1**

My axml layout is as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF">
<!-- Snip -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <fragment
        class="com.namespace.LoginFormView"
        android:id="@+id/sub_login_form"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="Visibility ShowLoginFormViewModel,Converter=Visibility" />
```

**Update 2**

It works fine when I build to a physical device

**Update 3**

If I add `[Register]` as per CheeseBaron's suggestion then the cause changes to:

```
[MonoDroid] Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.namespace.Droid.Views.LoginFormView that is not a Fragment
```

More info:

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] Android.Views.InflateException: Exception of type 'Android.Views.InflateException' was thrown.
[MonoDroid] at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x0004b>
[MonoDroid] at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue*) [0x00064] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d23da369/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:195
[MonoDroid] at Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate (int,Android.Views.ViewGroup,bool) [0x00082] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d23da369/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-16/src/generated/Android.Views.LayoutInflater.cs:687
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContext.CommonInflate (int,Android.Views.ViewGroup,Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Binders.IMvxLayoutInfactorFactory,bool) <IL 0x00030, 0x00136>
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContext.BindingInflate (int,Android.Views.ViewGroup,bool) <IL 0x00015, 0x000a5>
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContext.BindingInflate (int,Android.Views.ViewGroup) <IL 0x00004, 0x00044>
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.BindingInflate (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.IMvxBindingContextOwner,int,Android.Views.ViewGroup) <IL 0x0000f, 0x000f5>
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging.MvxFragmentActivity.SetContentView (int) <IL 0x00003, 0x00037>
[MonoDroid] at com.namespace.Droid.Views.LoginView.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x0000e] in /xxx/Ccom.namespace.Droid/Views/LoginView.cs:34
[MonoDroid] at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d23da369/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-16/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2374
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.facfe989-fd2b-40d3-bf63-959b844af987 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x0002b>
```

Comment: There are changes to Android inflation in 3.5.1 - caused to solve Xam Android Support package changes - release note is http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/. I suspect the inflation message you're quoting isn't coming from MvvmCross ... so my gut is telling me it's more likely to be to do with the Xam changes than Mvx differences. Certainly @cheesebaron's suggestion of adding the `[Register]` and then cleaning and rebuilding feels like it might help.

Comment: Thanks, but I've added [Register] and performed a Clean/Rebuild but still get the same error.

Comment: If you are still getting the same error - i.e. about md51537e9497dba76724980c8d1dff85301` then that means the `Register` is not working.

Comment: You're right the message had changed (I'd missed it) and now includes the full namespace. I've added 'Update 3'. I'm wondering if I should be using FullFragging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin.Android 5.1 introduces some breaking changes. This means you need to add `[Register("app.namespace.FragmentName")]` in all your Fragments.

For more information see:
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/987
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37277/stable-release-xamarin-android-5-1-0-breaking-changes-new-features-and-bug-fixes

EDIT:

OK! This is not related to #990. The problem is that for some reason the `MvxFragment` cannot be inflated as it is not recognized as a Fragment. When changing to minimum target 15 and the FullFragging MvvmCross nuget instead it starts to work.

Also remember, that **all** Java namespaces need to be lowercase. So when you use `[Register]` you must conform to that.

Your sample is also having two `MainLauncher` Activities, so I had to remove the default `MainActivity`. Your `FirstViewFragment` also defines an `Activity`, why does it do that???

So changes in short I made:

- Minimum target 15
- Replace Fragging with FullFragging
- Remove `[Activity]` flags from `FirstViewFragment`
- Lowercase namespace in `[Register]` in `FirstViewFragment`
- Change `FirstView` from `MvxFragmentActivity` to `MvxActivity`
- Remove `MainActivity`
- Replace `SupportFragmentManager` with `FragmentManager`
- Lowercase namespace in `class` in `FirstView.axml`

Then it works. Why the support version of framents in MvvmCross does not work needs to be investigated.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the attribute to the LoginFormView doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Alright might be related to https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/990 Can you maybe make a small repro sample?

Comment: Repro sample available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8l4fworjgtrdxy/FragmentTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: Worked, thanks. The only difference is I couldn't lowercase the 'class=' namespace as it throw an error. The 'Register' attribute is fully lowercase (namespace and class name)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by that, what is it that did not work? Name should be uppercase, but the Namespace should be lowercase. So something like: `com.abc.MyFragment`

Comment: @Cheesebaron what about fragments we cannot change? e.g. Google Maps' fragments named `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`

Comment: I'm using SupportFragmentManger and adding [Register] to all my views did the trick.

Comment: Nikola, I have the same issue you have.  Suddenly now my app is unable to inflate the com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.  If I find anything of use I will let you know.

Comment: A new example that handles this is available here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples